# Tableau This Year vs Last Year Comparison

Tags: calculation, tableau-api

I created a fiscal date calculation that compares This Year vs Last Year in Tableau

```
IF datediff('week',[Date],[Last Date])=1 then 'This Week'
ELSEIF datediff('week',[Date],[Last Date])=2 then 'Last Week'
ELSEIF datediff('week',[Date],[Last Date])<=13 AND datediff('week',[Date],[Last Date])>0 then 'Previous 11 Weeks'
ELSEIF datediff('week',[Date],[Last Date])<=65 AND datediff('week',[Date],[Last Date])>52 then 'LY'
END
```

However, because my new fiscal year started in February 2020 it is breaking. 
My goal is to create a calculation that will compare 2018 to 2019 and add on it as we go through 2020. So it will compare 2019 to 2020.

Essentially this is the logic. I just need to "translate it" so Tableau can read it. The viz should is in the bar chart.

2019 - (TY 2019 Week 52 vs LY 2018 Week52)  2020 (TY 2020 Week 1 vs LY 2019 Week1)

Comment: `datediff('week',[Date],[Last Date]) = 0 then 'This Week' ` should be correct logically. Right ? And as per your calculation it is taking `[Date]` as a reference for the start of year.